AbstractMethodError org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.getProviderUtil()Ljavax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil
I have an issue which is about using bean-validation api in Linux Server.
The problem is that bean validation works just fine in my local window PC. But when it runs in Cent OS. For some reasons, it does not work. I modified the log level to DEBUG to see the details of the problem. The folowing logs were shown.
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.getProviderUtil()Ljavax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil;
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1260)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:528)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:596)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:62)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:95)
        at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:86)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at com.nkia.itg.base.application.filter.HttpLogDataFilter.doFilter(HttpLogDataFilter.java:43)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at com.nkia.itg.base.application.filter.ReadableServletRequestFilter.doFilter(ReadableServletRequestFilter.java:20)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at com.nkia.itg.base.application.filter.ApplicationAccessFilter.doFilter(ApplicationAccessFilter.java:146)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at egovframework.rte.ptl.mvc.filter.HTMLTagFilter.doFilter(HTMLTagFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at com.nkia.itg.base.application.filter.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:30)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)


Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.getProviderUtil()Ljavax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil;
        at javax.persistence.Persistence$1.isLoaded(Persistence.java:93)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:137)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.isReachable(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1396)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1381)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:542)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:487)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:451)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:403)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:206)
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:772)
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.validateIfApplicable(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:159)
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:107)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:685)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)



Here's my jars i used.
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
      </dependency>

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
public class DevelopRequestBean {
    
    @NotBlank(message = ValidationMessage.COMPUTE_REQUEST_ID + ValidationMessage.NOT_BLANK)
    @NotNull(message = ValidationMessage.COMPUTE_REQUEST_ID + ValidationMessage.NOT_NULL)
    @ByteSize(max = 200, message = "Max : 200 byte")
    private String rqetId;  
    
    @NotBlank(message = ValidationMessage.COMPUTE_REQUEST_DIVISION + ValidationMessage.NOT_BLANK)
    @NotNull(message = ValidationMessage.COMPUTE_REQUEST_DIVISION + ValidationMessage.NOT_NULL)
    @ValidRqetDiv
    @ByteSize(max = 40, message = "Max : 40 byte")
    private String rqetDiv;

Since i use the old libraris of related hibernate jars such as hibernate-core and hibernate-entitymanger, i downgraded the version of hibernate-validator But it did not work as well.
The spring version is 3.2.9
